# Compiling VC++ program with Npcap in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, pcap, npcap

I am compiling the following program in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    pcap_if_t *alldevsp, *device;


    char errbuf[100];
    int count = 1;

    //First get the list of available devices
    printf("Finding available devices ... ");
    if (pcap_findalldevs(&alldevsp, errbuf))
    {
        printf("Error finding devices : %s", errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Done");

    //Print the available devices
    printf("\nAvailable Devices are :\n");
    for (device = alldevsp; device != NULL; device = device->next)
    {
        printf("%d. %s - %s\n", count, device->name, device->description);
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For pcap I have downloaded the library from [Npcap](https://github.com/nmap/npcap) project @ GitHub.
I installed the release for getting the DLL and using its SDK library for header and linker libraries. The installation of DLL is from the release package 0.0.8-r2 and SDK is from 0.0.7-r9.

Following several pointers over the net how to setup the environment, I have following setting.

1. Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> Path to header folder from SDK.
2. Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions -> WIN32 _DEBUG _CONSOLE WPCAP HAVE_REMOTE
3. Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directory -> Path to library folder from SDK.
4. Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> wpcap.lib Packet.lib

DLL from release exe gets installed in C:\Windows\System32\Npcap.
System is Windows 10 Home.

**Question:**

The above program compiles fine.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  HelloWorld.cpp
1>  HelloWorld.vcxproj -> C:\Users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\HelloWorld\Debug\HelloWorld.exe
1>  HelloWorld.vcxproj -> C:\Users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\HelloWorld\Debug\HelloWorld.pdb (Full PDB)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I run it, it was complaining about missing wpcap.dll file. I am new to VS as well as VC++, I googled and simplest technique I found just get over the issue, I copied the DLL from System32 to folder where .exe file was getting generated.

After this DLL issue went away, but now I am getting.

```
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HelloWorld\Debug\HelloWorld.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x160c has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
The thread 0xd5c has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
The thread 0x16c4 has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
The program '[9632] HelloWorld.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

I googled it, it seems there is mix of 64 bit and 32 bit DLL. I have no clue how to start debugging this issue.

I would really appreciate if some one guides me, to solve.

1. Better way (good practice in VC++ world) to find DLL instead of copying to exe folder.
2. Tips on how to find which DLL is causing the issue.

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the configuration, your `HelloWorld.exe` is a 32-bit (x86) program. I assume that you are using a x64 Windows OS, so `C:\Windows\System32\Npcap` is for x64 DLLs. And `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Npcap` is for x86 DLLs.

You got the `0xc000007b` error because your x86 `HelloWorld.exe` is trying to load Npcap's x64 DLLs, which is definitely not right.

So the solution is to copy the DLLs (`wpcap.dll`, `Packet.dll`) from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Npcap` to folder where .exe file was getting generated.

Another way is adding `C:\Windows\System32` to the `PATH` environment variable. So your x86 and x64 binaries will always find the correct Npcap DLLs no matter where they are located.